# awk won't use '||' as a field delimiter

Tags: awk

I am trying to use awk to cut with multi-character delimiter

```
echo 'f1##f2' |awk -F '##' '{print $2}'
```

It prints `f2`. Whereas

```
echo 'f1||f2' |awk -F '||' '{print $1}'
```

prints `f1||f2`.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: I'm surprised that GNU `awk` allows that at all. BSD `awk` throws an error, `awk: illegal primary in regular expression || at |`, as does `mawk`, `mawk: line 0: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, the behaviour is unspecified by POSIX. The GNU behaviour is more useful and makes more sense IMO. It makes more sense to me to have `(foo|bar|)` be like `(foo|bar)?` rather than returning an error. That's also what perl REs do. `?` in zsh globs is done that (`?` meaning something different in globs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The vertical bar char `|` is treated as special character in your case and should be escaped:

```
echo "f1||f2" |awk -F'\\|\\|' '{print $1}'
f1
```

---

As an alternative you may put `|` into the character class:

```
echo "f1||f2||f3" |awk -F'[|]{2}' '{print $3}'
f3
```

Comment: Why escape it twice?

Comment: @pfnuesel, because with this `-F'\\||'` you'll get empty `{print $2}` (second field)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, FYI: linguistically `|` **IS** "vertical bar" char (not OR character), semantically - in some context it's logical `OR` operator, in some other context - regex alternation operator

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  Adding to the comment of RomanPerekhrest: Calling `|` an OR character is confusing because there is an actual OR character which is different: "∨" (*Logical Or*, U+2228, in Unicode block *Mathematical Operators* ). (In some fonts, it may look almost like the alphabet letter *V* in uppercase. It should be larger and have a larger angle.)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I was talking about its meaning in the language not the character name. In a regexp it is apparently called alternation, though I call it OR (not logical OR).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes, I understood what you meant. It's mostly about saying *character* when actually a language symbol is meant. But I do not say I had wrote something better than your comment - it's more that I'm building "on the shoulders" of your comment!